# Need to click on element twice to execute two click handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm writing a Tic-Tac-Toe game that calls on an API that allows users to log in / register, create games, access saved in-progress games, play with others, etc. I'm having a lot of trouble currently with accessing saved games. When you click on the HTML element with the ID "show", I want two separate things to happen: I should see the "result" div populated with the JSON retrieved, and I should visually see in the board divs (numbered 0 through 8) where current players in the game are.

Currently, I need to click on "show" twice in order for both of these things to happen. On the first click, I see the JSON rendered in the "result" div (basically everything in _displayInProgressGame / GameAJAX.displayInProgressGame happens). On the second click, The board HTML is updated (displayInProgressGameUI).

Here's my AJAX - the goal of this code is to show the retrieved JSON game data in a #result div, and set my local board data (which, if I hadn't yet started a game, would just be an array with 9 empty strings) equal to the board data in JSON (example: ['X', 'O', '', '', '', '', 'X', '', '']):

```
var _displayInProgressGame = function(){
  $.ajax(sa + '/games/' + $('#show-input').val(), {
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Token token=' + $('#token').val()
    }
  }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqxhr){
    $('#result').val(JSON.stringify(data));
    for (var i = 0; i < (data.game.cells).length; i++) {
      if (data.game.cells[i]) {
        Game.addToBoard(data.game.cells[i],i);
      }
    }
  }).fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    $('#result').val('show failed');
  });
  };
```

And here's the JS code for the other half of displaying an in-progress game. This code calls the function described above, renders the board HTML based on my local board data (the array I described above), checks a third logic JS file (everything you see that starts with "Game." comes from this third file) to see if the game is over (checks for a tie or a win), and does some other stuff like increment a count of the moves made so far.

```
var displayInProgressGameUI = function(){
  GameAJAX.displayInProgressGame();
  Game.board().forEach(function(cell){
    if (cell) {
      Game.incrementMoveCount();
    }
  });
  if (Game.isGameOver()) {
    $prompt.show();
    $prompt.html('This game has already ended! Click New Game to play another.');
    gameOverUI();
  }
  $('#0').text(Game.board()[0]);
  $('#1').text(Game.board()[1]);
  $('#2').text(Game.board()[2]);
  $('#3').text(Game.board()[3]);
  $('#4').text(Game.board()[4]);
  $('#5').text(Game.board()[5]);
  $('#6').text(Game.board()[6]);
  $('#7').text(Game.board()[7]);
  $('#8').text(Game.board()[8]);
};

$('#show').on('click', displayInProgressGameUI);
```

I'm almost certain that this has something to do with the order in which everything is called, or that the if statements in the my displayInProgressGameUI function are messing things up.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Tic Tac Toe](http://www.ashok.im/TicTacToe.html)

Comment: Hard to tell precisely what your issue is without some sort of demo that replicates it and seeing all the code. However iif `GameAJAX.displayInProgressGame()` is calling the function with the ajax...you are trying to loop over results before they are returned ....ajax is asynchronous. What is likely happening is the second click is using data from first request. This assumes that `Game.board()` is returning the data from request. It's hard to help more because the snippets shown aren't connected with the limited code shown

Comment: Short answer is you need to render the board from the done callback of ajax or return the ajax  promise from `GameAJAX.displayInProgressGame()` and render in that promise callback